# How to ensure even vertical spacing around horizontal lines drawn with \rule?

Tags: vertical-alignment

I'm new to LaTeX and I'm trying to write my CV in it. I'm happy with the result so far but I would like to be able to ensure even vertical spacing around the horizontal lines. In other words, I'm trying to get the text in the \parbox's to be vertically centered between the two horizontal lines, and to apply the same to the word 'Employment'.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\begin{document}
\raggedright\parbox[t]{10cm}{{\huge Firstname Lastname}} \hfill
\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\newline
\raggedright\parbox[t]{5cm}{22 Street Street\\
9999, Capital, Country} \hfill \parbox[t]{5cm}{Address Address\\Address Address\\Capital, Country\\} \hfill \parbox[t]{6cm}{name.name@name.com\\+phonenumer1\\+phonenumber2}
\mbox{}
\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
\par\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\vspace{-2\baselineskip}
\section{Employment}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\begin{itemize}
\item[]\parbox{14cm}{{\large{{\scshape My Current Employer With the Long Name (MCE)}}}\\Info I need to include about said employer} \hfill \parbox{3cm}{\raggedleft{\itshape 2014 --- present\\City, Country}}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! As standard `\section` and friends introduce stretchable space (glue) before and after them.  Thus either you should avoid them here, or adjust their definitions.  The `titlesec` package provides an interface to do the latter.

Comment: Thank you, @AndrewSwann. Glad to be here and I'm looking forward to learn more about TeX.